# How to swipe ListView nested in SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have a `ListView` nested inside a `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

I want to swipe from anywhere in the `ListView`, down to an element at the bottom of the layout, such that a swipe event occurs, and the little refresh icon is observed.

[image]

I have tried this

```
new TouchAction(mUser.mDriver)
    .longPress(listView)
    .moveTo(bottomElement)
    .release()
    .perform();
```

and this

```
new TouchAction(mUser.mDriver)
    .longPress(swipeView)
    .moveTo(bottomElement)
    .release()
    .perform();
```

And neither appear to work.

How do I swipe a list view with appium using Java Client?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
WebElement swipeView = myDriver.findElementById(myId);

new TouchAction(mUser.mDriver)
       .press(getXMiddle(swipeView), getYUp(swipeView))
       .moveTo(getXMiddle(swipeView), getYDown(swipeView))
       .release()
       .perform();
```

and the helper methods

```
// x locations

public int getXLeft(WebElement el)
{
  return el.getLocation().getX();
}

public int getXRight(WebElement el)
{
  return getXLeft(el) + el.getSize().getWidth();
}

public int getXMiddle(WebElement el)
{
  return (getXRight(el) + getXLeft(el)) / 2;
}

// y locations

public int getYUp(WebElement el)
{
  return el.getLocation().getY();
}

public int getYDown(WebElement el)
{
  return getYUp(el) + el.getSize().getHeight();
}

public int getYMiddle(WebElement el)
{
  return (getYUp(el) + getYDown(el)) / 2;
}
```